# Accessing fasttext vectors in spaCy

Tags: nlp, nltk, spacy, fasttext, spacy-3

I have converted the **fasttext** vectors into spacy format using `init` command. It has been done successfully as shown below;

```
ℹ Creating blank nlp object for language 'en'
✔ Successfully converted 400873 vectors
✔ Saved nlp object with vectors to output directory. You can now use the path to
it in your config as the 'vectors' setting in [initialize].
E:\Spacy\output_dir
```

Here it says that I have to set the path of vectors to **E:\Spacy\output_dir** in **config.cfg** file. Now there are two **config.cfg** files, one default file and the other one created in the **E:\Spacy\output_dir** . Which one to update? I have updated the default one and executed the following code;

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank('en')
#print(nlp.initialize())
nlp.vocab['ਵਿਭਾਗ'].vector
```

In this code, I am trying to access vectors but it is giving the following error;

```
ValueError: [E010] Word vectors set to length 0. This may be because you don't have a model installed or loaded, or because your model doesn't include word vectors. For more info, see the docs:
https://spacy.io/usage/models
```

Where am I making the mistake?

When I am using the following code I am able to see the vectors;

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('E:\Spacy\output_dir')
#print(len(nlp.vocab.strings))
nlp.vocab['ਵਿਭਾਗ'].vector
```

Can't I access the vectors without loading the model? What for is `vectors` inside the **config.cfg** then? Please explain.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Kindly give your valuable inputs for the above question as well!